# Map ng-model array values with the object of ng-options for selected options

Tags: angularjs, components, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I have following values:

```
campaign_sms_templates = [11,22];
```

and

```
templateSMSList = [
{"id":11, "name":"test"},
{"id":12, "name":"test 12"},
{"id":22, "name":"test 22"}
];
```

And angular code is like:

```
<select multiple="multiple"
   ng-model="campaign_sms_templates"
   ng-options="value as value.name for value in templateSMSList track by value.id">
</select>
```

But values are not selected on rendering. When I change `campaign_sms_templates` parameter values with:

```
campaign_sms_templates = [ {"id":11}, {"id":22} ];
```

It works as objects matches and on rendering it displays selected values.

Can anyone help, how I can render selected options by using these values:

```
campaign_sms_templates = [11,22];
```

Please do let me know if is there anything need more clarifications.

Comment: well select works that way, do you mind mapping your array to array of objects before you bind to view .

Comment: thanks @supercool  just resolved the problem after spending lots of hours in this :( please check and share your feedback .

Answer (score 0):

After spending lots of time in this, now finally I have resolved this

```
<select multiple="multiple" ng-change="save(campaign_sms_templates)" ng-model="campaign_sms_templates">
    <option value=[[field.id]] ng-repeat="field in templateSMSList" ng-selected="campaign_sms_templates.indexOf(field.id)!==-1">[[field.name]]</option>
</select>
```

It seems not a good practice but as I only want to save ids in my database documents so I did this.

Any feedback are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use `value.id as value.name for value`:

```
<select multiple="multiple"
   ng-model="campaign_sms_templates"
   ng-options="value.id as value.name for value in templateSMSList">
</select>
```

Also leave out the `track by expression` as it is not needed and will break the directive.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-options Directive API Reference - `select as` and `track by`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-and-track-by-).